# Simple Mapper Pattern C# Code Generation Template

Tags: c#, orm, code-generation, dao

Can anybody recommend a decent C# [Mapper Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) code generation template that plays nicely with SQL stored procedures?  I'm looking for something that generates [POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/define-poco) style entity objects, with a static mapper class for transferring data to/from the database through entity objects.

I understand that NHibernate can generate POCO style entity objects; however, NHibernate looses its appeal when you have a strong dependency on SQL stored procedures (which is a requirement of this project).

Bonus points awarded if you can also recommend a template that also generates the CRUD stored procs! ;-)

**Edit:** For this particular project, I am definitely not interested in any templates that generate Active Record pattern code (e.g, Subsonic, Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very old, but free LLBLGen will generate CRUD stored procedures. It will also generate objects, but I forget how much like POCOs they are. I have a feeling there are more guts in them than not.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/usingllblgen.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [My Generation](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) and using it to create your own templates?

Comment: I did look into My Generation (this post is relatively old now). I was just curious if there was anything out there that already existed.