# What does "Class POCO"?

Tags: generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define 'poco'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/define-poco)

What does "Class POCO"?

Comment: I think you're going to need to elaborate a bit on your question... or take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/define-poco

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of POCO is "Plain Old CLR Object".  This is commonly used to describe objects when using the Entity Framework.  For example

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/11/sneak-preview-persistence-ignorance-and-poco-in-entity-framework-4-0.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx

It would really help though if you gave us more context.  In particular what language or environment you're referring to.

Comment: I was referring just to the Entity Framework...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that comes into my mind is the abbreviation "POCO" for "Plain old C-Object" (or "POJO" for "Plain old Java-Object") which denominates a very simple Object that only has some simple attributes and setters/getters for this - no other logic or functionality.