# How to create POCO class

Tags: c#, poco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['POCO' definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition)

i have simple class called books. It need to be converted into POCO class. What changes. need to be done?

```
class **BOOKS**
{
    private string authorName;
    public string *getName*
       {
          return authorName;
       }
    public string *setName*
       {
         authorName=value;
      }
}
```

non static class with 2 props.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition

Comment: Well, this class already looks like a POCO to me, just use properties instead of getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

No changes - you're ***poco ready*** :-D

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Book
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Property must return List<>. Need to add Name and email for every author. How? 

   static class testClass<T>{
private static List<String> _fname = new List<string>(new string[] { "Madra", "Bangalore", "Hyderabad", "Bombay", "Trivandrum" });
        public static List<String> Fname
        { get { return _fname; } }

    }
Is it POCO ready? 
If yes how to instantiate and call from any Main()?

Answer (score 0):

Per biziclop's link, it probably already is a Plain Old C# Object.  But to make it plainer, you could write it like this:

```
class BOOKS
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

This feature is called [Auto-Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), and was introduced with C# 3.0

Answer (score 0):

If your class doesn't include any third party attributes in your class.

Please check out the MSDN link about POCO.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681329.aspx

In your above code, replace the two methods with a single property.

```
private string _authorName;
public string AuthorName
{
    get
    {
        return _authorName;
    }
    set
    {
        _authorName=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Property must return List<>. Need to add Name and email for every author. How? 

Can i use this code,

 static class testClass<T>
    {
        private static List<String> fname = new List<string>(new string[] { "Madra", "Bangalore", "Hyderabad", "Bombay", "Trivandrum" });
        public static List<String> testProp
        { get { return fname; } }

    }
Is it POCO ready? 
If yes how to instantiate and call from any Main()?