# using WebServices to read Customers Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dataset, asmx

I want to make WebMethod to my WebForms,
beforehand this is my function

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetCustomersData()
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnString"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string commandstr = "select * from Customers ORDER BY CustomerID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandstr, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet SqlDs = new DataSet();
            SqlDa.Fill(SqlDs, "TableCustomer");
            if(SqlDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return SqlDs;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Actually I want to BindData from WebServices to DataGridView in my WebForm, is there any possible way ?

Comment: DataSet contains a lot of addtional data that would be transferred over the network. (i.e XSD schema etc.) So I would create a list based on the items in the DataSet and returned just this list.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: thank you for your help, therefore I should learn more advance Restful Architecture using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a [POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition) class and return a list of this class instead. Dataset contains a lots of aditional data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use web service methods in your application, you have to separate web service project and web project. Here are the steps you should follow.

- Create a web service project.
- Write you web method in your project.
- Publish your web project.
- Host your web project in a server. This step will allow you to reach your methods like http://www.example.com/Service1.asmx

When your web service is ready, you should follow these steps.
- Create a web application project that contains your web pages.
- Add the web service, you created, to your web application project as reference.
- Use the web service method to bind data to your datagridview.