# How to catch PropertyChanged events in multiple Views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I recently started learning about WPF, which led me to learn about MVVM and eventually MVVM Light, so still a starter in these three. I am building an application with a layout similar to the picture in the link -> [Application layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzLuw.png)

In order to maintain good code separation and avoid huge files i decided the best approach would be to create a main *View*, and in that create several smaller *Views* per "zone" of the UI. From what i read in several tutorials, it is advised to maintain 1 *ViewModel* per *View*. Therefore i have a *Master View / ViewModel*, and several *View / ViewModels* running simultaneously.

Finally i have a single *Model* that keeps track of the information I plan to display in the UI. The *Model* interacts with an external API that can modify the data in it. So besides data being modified by user request (ex: pressing buttons or timers), the data will also change with asynchronous events from the API. Which means I need two way communication between the *Model* and the *ViewModels / Views*.

**The questions:**

**1.** Do you agree with the "1 view per zone of the UI"? And the 1 ViewModel per View?

**2.** In the Main View-Code-Behind I instantiate all the ViewModels, and in each View I bind them like in the MVVM Light examples i saw:

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding SideBar, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding TopBar, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Is this the correct way to instantiate and bind several ViewModels to the respective Views?

**3.** Each ViewModel is passed a reference to the Main ViewModel (except the Main itself) in its constructor, which is the only one with a reference to the Model. This is how i connect the several ViewModels to the Model. Is this conceptually correct?

**4.** Initially i was trying to avoid using MVVM Light or other frameworks if i could do all i wanted with the RaisePropertyChanged method. I might be doing something wrong, but for example, when the Model calls RaisePropertyChanged, i can catch that event in the Main ViewModel, however it doesn't propagate to the rest of the ViewModels, so i had to do it myself by calling RaisePropertyChanged a second time:

```
public MountainTopViewModel()
{
    _model = new MachineStatusModel();
    _model.PropertyChanged += ModelPropertyChanged;
}


void ModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "TestVarModel")
    {
        // do something else if needed
        RaisePropertyChanged("TestVar");
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is either not the correct way to do it, or there is a better one. So how can I inform all the Views and ViewModels when a property changes in the Model, without having to re-call the method in different places?

Sorry for the long story, i would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems unwise to me:

> The Model interacts with an external API that can modify the data in it. So besides data being modified by user request (ex: pressing buttons or timers), the data will also change with asynchronous events from the API. Which means I need two way communication between the Model and the ViewModels / Views.

I would have the async API events driving changes in the viewmodel, *not* the model. Then, in response to changes from the async API *or* from the View, the viewmodel does its usual thing: Updates the model and raises events which the view responds to. The viewmodel already plays that role, so use what you've got. Your scheme adds complexity that you don't need, and it's more complexity than you may realize. Item # **4** in your question is just the tip of the iceberg of that added complexity; believe me, it'll only get uglier from there. Don't do that to yourself. You're young. You've got everything to live for.

It's not unusual for a viewmodel to handle the `PropertyChanged` event of another viewmodel, or for a viewmodel to expose specific custom events which fire when specific properties change value. It might have a `NameChanged` event or whatever. But I don't see any particular need for that in your question, as I understand it.

**1.** Yes.

**2.** If MVVMLight does things the way you've got it there, do that. Plunkett's Razor: **Whenever possible, conform to the practices of the framework you're using.** Consistency is golden in programming for many reasons, and if you follow the "rules", you'll usually find the framework will be there waiting to help you instead of fighting you every step of the way. This isn't a law of nature, but it's an amazingly reliable rule of thumb.

**3.** That's conceptually a little shaky. Ideally, we try to write viewmodels that aren't dependent on "parent" viewmodels. Your `Library` viewmodel has to know what a `Book` viewmodel is because it contains a collection of them, but a `Book` viewmodel can often be more useful if it doesn't depend on a `Library`. Imagine writing a `Wheel` that's got all kinds of dependencies on `Car`, and then having to implement `Bicycle`. Do you give `Bicycle` an `Alternator`, or do you create a dummy `Car`? Times like that you start to daydream about moving to a commune in Vermont and making useful objects out of wood.

I would probably have a model type for each viewmodel, and give all the viewmodels a reference to their own model in their constructors. The models would probably have the same parent-child relationship as the viewmodels. If your model is Entity Framework or something instead of ["POCO" classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition), then yeah, one model for everybody or whatever. But still, just hand it to them directly.

Comment: "I would have the async API events driving changes in the viewmodel, not the model."

I also like that idea, so i will follow your advice on this one. The Model will only act as a place to hold the information (as it usually is from what i read so far), and the ViewModels will trigger the events that change the information there, either from GUI events or API events. Also every ViewModel will have a reference to the Model, this way the ViewModels can get all the information they need without having to know about each other.

And thanks for a couple of laughs!