# How to access the Root member of Object

Tags: c#, json, object

I currently have something like this

```
object t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(mystring);
```

Now when I browse it, it has a property "Root" which has a string in it that I need. How do I access that property?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [`POCO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition) class:

```
public class Poco
{  
    [JsonProperty("Root")]
    public string Root { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can [deserialize your JSON to this specified type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) and access their properties, something like this:

```
var root = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poco>(mystring)).Root;
```