# Is my c# class a poco class if i refer other class type in my class?

Tags: c#, poco

I have a class that looks like this

```
public class ClassA
{
   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public int variable1{get;set}

   [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
   public ClassB variable2{get;set;}
}
```

And Class B looks like this

```
public class classB
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    int variable3{get;set}

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    ClassC variable4{get;set}

}
```

Since i am referring Class B type in this class, is this still considered as a poco class?

Comment: Very much based on your opinion of a) how you define a poco and/or b) whether you class any data model as poco so long as the serialiser can serialise it.

Comment: What does the ```ClassB``` look like? If it's a POCO class as well, you're good to go.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250001/poco-definition

Comment: @Shawn, I have updated how my ClassB looks like

Comment: Originally I would have said yes however since your update, you are using `JsonProperty` which is iirc from JSON.Net meaning that you do depend on an external framework and so they wouldn't qualify as POCOs.